# Inconsistency between \int_compare and \fp_compare when dealing with logical operators

Tags: expl3, latex3

I understand that the less automatic solution to compare multiple integer logical statements is by using `\int_compare_p:nNn {...}{...}{...}` along with `\bool_if:nTF {condition(s)}{true}{false}`. My question is why does `\fp_compare:nTF {...}{...}{...}` works fine with logical operators but `\int_compare:nTF {...}{...}{...}` yield an error even though all of the values used are integers?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\compare}{mmm}{
  \fp_compare:nTF {#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\compareHardcode}{mm}{
  \bool_if:nTF {
    \int_compare_p:nNn {1} < {2} && \int_compare_p:nNn {2} < {3}
  }{#1}{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\compareError}{mmm}{
  %will not work using \int_compare:nTF 
  \int_compare:nTF {#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \compare{1 < 2 && 2 < 3}{yes}{no} % prints yes
  \compareHardcode{yes}{no}         % prints yes
  % Erroneous line commented:
  % \compareError{1 < 2 && 2 < 3}{yes}{no}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because it is documented behaviour... Use `\int_compare:nTF { 1 < 2 < 3} {yes} {no}` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon, thank you for the suggestion. I wonder *why* this is the case?

Comment: The only reason I can tell is: Because it was coded and documented that way. Maybe a kernel-team member knows the reason behind this decision...

Comment: @M.AlJumaily the underling `\ifnum` and l3fp tests are very different, so there are limits on how far you can make things look the same, but I don't recall this difference being specifically discussed,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I would appreciate knowing the exact reason.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily egreg has already shown a major difference, but why do you expect an exact reason? things.are the same if someone actively decides to make them the same, by default things work differently. so the question is not why are they different, but why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I understand where you and egreg are coming from. Let elaborate further. Typical programming languages tend to not differentiate between integers and fp when it comes to logical operators (I will leave out the notion of implicit and explicit casting). Furthermore, how can I automate comparing integers *without* using `\fp_compare:nTF`? Lastly, in the case where I use `\fp_compare:nTF` for integer comparison, would there be any downside to this?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily typical languages provide floating point. tex does not.  l3's int expressions are a thin wrapper around the primitive `\numexpr` and do not have infix conditional expressions. You can combine integer comparisons using l3boolean functions, just not as inline int expressions. l3fp is different as it is not based on any tex provided expression syntax.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thank you for the clarification. I now understand that the structure of fp is fundamentally different than integers. I will assume l3boolean is what `Interface3` refers to as *The boolean data type* (section 9.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `2<3` is a valid ⟨fp expr⟩ and `\fp_eval:n { 2<3 }` returns 1. You can also use logical operators. Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{1<2}

\fpeval{1<2 && 2<3}

\fpeval{1<2 || 3<2}

\fpeval{1>2 || 3<2}

\end{document}
```

This prints

1
1
1
0

So `\fp_compare:nTF { 1<2 && 2<3 } { yes } { no }` returns “yes”, because the evaluation is 1, which is nonzero.

To the contrary, `1<2` is not a valid ⟨int expr⟩. Moreover, you cannot use `\int_compare:nTF { 1<2 && 2<3 } { yes } { no }`, because the argument is invalid: the argument has to be in the form

⟨int expr⟩⟨relation⟩⟨int expr⟩⟨relation⟩…⟨int expr⟩⟨relation⟩⟨int expr⟩

and logical operators are not allowed.

Comment: Could you say where `\fpeval` is documented? (I tried the clsguide, xparse and (not very hopefully) interface3.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I wonder why fp logic works as expected (even though there might be issues with rounding) but integer logic doesn't work? If anything, I would imagine that fp logic would be problematic rather than integer logic.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily Integer expressions are bound by the implementation of `\numexpr` in e-TeX; to the contrary, fp-expressions are completely implemented in the kernel (and are much slower).